# vb.net mysql insert commande with date

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, date, insert

i want to insert into the table from vb.net and i get this error "Incorrect datetime value: '28/03/2020' for function str_to_date"

```
  cmd.CommandText = "insert into ventes (idc,totale,date) value (@P1, @P2,STR_TO_DATE(@P3,'%d-%M-%Y'))"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", ComboBox2.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2", TextBox12.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P3", TextBox2.Text)
```

Comment: Why not use a `DateTimePicker` in the first place? Unless you need to be able to handle NULL dates, which it appears you don't, it's a no-brainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe read about how to specify a date format [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp). According to that, `%M` is for the month name in full while `%m` is for the month as a number. It took me less than a minute to find that information by simply searching for "mysql str_to_date". If a solution is that easy to find, the question should not have been asked in the first place.

Comment: It appears that you also specified dashes in your format specifier when your value contains slashes.